# New to Ruby, looking for style tips on this function

Tags: ruby

I am brand new to both Ruby and Stackoverflow.

Below is some code for a function I wrote. The question isn't really specific to the function, just an example of something I wrote. The function takes in a string of any number of words, and reverses the order of the words. Also, for each word, it takes the vowels and moves it to the end of the word. It also downcases everything. Thus, "Hello World!" would become "wrld!o hlleo".

I am trying to use some Ruby features, hence why it is a one-liner so to speak. Basically I am just looking for style suggestions. Is it appropriate to do such a thing in this manner (one line?). I'm sure there are functions that could accomplish the task quicker, so I am open to those suggestions too, since my code is very long and convoluted. Also I should mention I wanted to write this with only base Ruby, no extra packages/gems.

```
  def funky_words(s)
    s.strip.gsub(/\s+/, " ").split(" ").reverse.instance_eval{map{|elt| elt.gsub(/([aeiou])/i,"")}}.
    zip(s.strip.split(" ").reverse.map{|elt| elt.scan(/([aeiou])/i).flatten}.instance_eval{map{|elt| elt.join}}).
    map(&:join).join(" ").downcase
    #first "line" reverses word order removes vowels, second "line" captures vowels and moves them to the end, 
   #last "line" joins the new funky words.
  end
```

Comment: If your code works as expected and your target is "refactoring", consider posting to [code review[(https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Consider writing that as follows: `" Hello World!".strip.downcase.squeeze(' ').reverse.gsub(/[^ ]+/) do |word|; word.each_char.with_object('') do |c,str|; if 'aeiou'.include?(c); str << c; else; str.insert(0,c); end; end; end #=> "wrld!o hlloe"`. Note the string is not converted to an array of words and the order of the vowels placed at the end is not maintained. If vowel order is to be maintained build strings of non-vowels and vowels within `gsub`'s block and combine them at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you want you code to follow best practices, as agreed upon by Ruby community, use [Rubocop](https://docs.rubocop.org/). It’s a tool that combines linter with style analyzer.

If you prefer to check your style manually, you can read the guidelines [here](https://rubystyle.guide/).

Answer (score 0):

This question is about style, so I am not commenting on the correctness of the code or other ways to write it.

Some developers would prefer this very long line to be broken up into 2-3 separate statements, more or less split up by logic or functionality. This would improve readability and make the code easier to maintain.

The first step in improving style is to use [RuboCop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop), as suggested by Konrad. It will find style issues, and/or automatically reformat the code. RuboCop can be run on the command line for a single or multiple files, or for the entire project. You can also run RuboCop inside your editor.

See an example output of the RuboCop that was executed on your code below. Note that it does not create separate statements, which in this case could be more readable. It simply breaks the long lines into multiple lines (not ideal, but more readable than the original). It also reformats a few other items: make chained calls on multiple lines start with `.`, add space after comment (`#` ), fix spaces inside brackets and braces, etc.

```
def funky_words(s)
  s.strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').split(' ').reverse.instance_eval { map { |elt| elt.gsub(/([aeiou])/i, '') } }
   .zip(s.strip.split(' ').reverse.map { |elt| elt.scan(/([aeiou])/i).flatten }.instance_eval { map(&:join) })
   .map(&:join).join(' ').downcase
  # first "line" reverses word order removes vowels, second "line" captures vowels and moves them to the end,
  # last "line" joins the new funky words.
end
```

Note that you can change the RuboCop settings from their default values and even disable some rules (called cops). For example, I am using longer max line length.

**SEE ALSO:**

[RuboCop docs](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/index.html)
[Change RuboCop settings](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html)
[Disable cops (rules) in your source code](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#disabling-cops-within-source-code)